# C# HTMLDecode without System.Web possible?

Tags: c#, html-encode

I know there are different methods in the System.Web namespace for decoding html entities (such as "%20" for space). I'm building a Winforms application however, but needs to deal with html encoded strings. Basically I have the iTunes Library XML file and need to decode the URLs in there to check the files.

Is this possible without the System.Web namespace?

Comment: Why would you not use the System.Web namespace?

Comment: This is relevant if you want to use the client only subset of the framework, +1.

Comment: @Cookey see bizon's answer, definitely the best one.

Comment: I suspect the chosen answer is out of date and should be changed

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Developers who need to use System.Web.HttpUtility in their client apps and had to reference System.Web.dll and therefore target NET4
>   full (System.Web.dll is in Full) , can now target the NET4 Client
>   Profile by using the new System.Net.WebUtility class which is in
>   System.dll (System.dll is in NET4 Client Profile). 
>   System.Net.WebUtility includes HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode. Url encoding
>   can be accomplished using the System.Uri class (also in System.dll).

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode.aspx):

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

Answer (score 24):

Just because you're writing a Windows Forms app doesn't stop you from using `System.Web`. Just add a reference to `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: I have tripped on this before. I forgot the reference, thought a "using" would do. Thanks!

Comment: The issue with that is that you can't use the .NET 3.5 Client profile with your .NET app so your XP users can avoid the 150mb download and go for the smaller 28mb one. Best to avoid the System.Web namespace if you can.

Comment: I second that, It´s silly a subset of these methods couldn't be provided in a seperate assembly available for the client profile installation.. i find myself quite often needing them in simple client apps.

Comment: @Almund: Check my answer. They did it.

Answer (score 8):

See [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/617930.aspx) if you're still curious how to do this without System.Web.  It offers a solution for URI decoding (which is really what you're decoding, not HTML entities which are something like "&emdash;" )

Answer (score 0):

To use the methods that are in the .NET framework you must use the System.Web namespace to get the HtmlDecode method.

Yes, you could write your own method to do it, but that wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Just add the reference to system.web.

Answer (score 0):

mybe it can help in winforms :

```
System.Uri.EscapeUriString(plainText);
```

Comment: Do you mind expanding on your code instead of posting a one liner?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` or `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`

Comment: Since the question was how to do this Without the System.Web assembly I´m afraid this isn't much help..