# Call to System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode throws StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, html, stack-overflow, system.web

I have inherited some code where a call like:

```
var test = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("google");
```

causes a stackoverflow.  A call to WebUtility.HtmlDecode in the same place works fine.  I've Googled around but not found anything about why this might be happening.

It is not a web application - and I see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says to use WebUtility in this case - but other sources say I can just add a ref to System.Web and it will work fine - e.g. [C# HTMLDecode without System.Web possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711672/c-sharp-htmldecode-without-system-web-possible)  I have built a test app and the same call to HtmlDecode works fine.

The stack trace is:

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.StaticInit()  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.HttpRuntime() Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.FusionInited.get()    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(string typeName = "System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder", bool throwOnError = true, bool ignoreCase = false)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(string typeName = "System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder", string propertyName = "encoderType", System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement configElement = {System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection}, System.Xml.XmlNode node = null, bool checkAptcaBit = true, bool ignoreCase = false)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(string typeName = "System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder", string propertyName = "encoderType", System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement configElement = {System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection}, bool checkAptcaBit = true, bool ignoreCase = false)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(string typeName = "System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder", string propertyName = "encoderType", System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement configElement = {System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection}, bool checkAptcaBit = true)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(string typeName = "System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder", string propertyName = "encoderType", System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement configElement = {System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection})   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder>.CreateValue() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder>.LazyInitValue()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Lazy<System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder>.Value.get()   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.Current.get()    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string s = "Google")   Unknown
```

I'd like to understand the source of the problem if anyone knows the answer!

Comment: Isn't the nature of a stackoverflow that you don't get a stack trace? The stack trace you provide doesn't look very "overflowy".

Comment: Maybe it is a feature of VS2015 - I definitely have both an overflow exception and a stack trace!